# Css-update with bug?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, top-bar, css

Since about an hour or so, the dropdown arrow in the "StackExchange" menu has disappeared for me (tested on Safari and Chrome), clicking on it leads straight to https://stackexchange.com and I had to type in the url to get to meta.

On StackExchange itself, the dropdown menu looks normal, but it seems like on e.g. tex.stackexchange the problem is the same.)

Comment: New top bar. The site switcher is now on the right. I'll find a relevant post on über-meta.

Comment: Oh, silly me. How could I not have seen that... (But I really don't like the click me to get to stackexchange.com in the lop left.) I'm going to click that button by mistake at least 100 times before I learn!

Comment: [See here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300869/354333). People having the new top bar before have been unhappy with that for a while.

Comment: Tangentially, to click there to go to stackexchange is not really new, I think. It is just that the element *also* had the dropdown aspect. This dual purpose sometimes causes issues. Thus the element was disentangled. That said, I agree that new design needs a bit getting used to. But after some time I feel it works alright. (I had a bit of a head start, as a mod on a different site.)

Comment: Also, @mrf.  In addition to the link that Daniel provides (Sept 13, 2017), we have today's post [New top bar is live](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301845/new-top-bar-is-live)  Anyone feels strongly about the change (yay or nay), or have questions about the new top bar, can go to the link here and comment below the post, or else use an  answer field to write your concerns.  I checked and was assured that feedback regarding the current upper-bar will be taken seriously; that SE is open to feedback from users, including mods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Today, a [new topbar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301845/new-top-bar-is-live) was rolled out. One of the changes is the location of the site-switcher, which is now on the right. The Stack Exchange logo on the left now takes one to https:/stackexchange.com. The change [is not universally loved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/301848/177145).

Comment: Yes, I had a quick look at some of the threads at über-meta, and it seems I'm not the only one disapproving of the new behavior of the top-left button..

Comment: Where one users access the help menu (formerly it appeared on the top bar, with a drop down menu)?  That actually sets back this site for both askers who need help, and commenters who want to link an asker to the help menu for any of several reasons.

Comment: @amWhy In the site switcher dropdown, there are links to help and chat of the site one is currently on. Once one got used to it, it's not more inconvenient than the previous location. Two clicks either way, one to open the dropdown, one to get to the help centre.

Comment: Okay, but having an identifier (***help***) actually listed in the top bar will more likely be used (by new users)  than will some undefined link that must be linked in order to see how to access help.

Comment: Yeah. That was at some time also brought up when the new top bar came out on SO, but the decision wasn't changed.

Comment: When you hover over the rightmost icon on the right-hand side, one reads "A list of all 171 Stack Exchange sites."  Why would we expect users, especially very new users to know that "A list of all 171 SE sites" will allow them to click for help?

Comment: Don't ask me. All I know is that change is bad. Almost always.

Comment: Oh, I didn't  mean to direct my last question to you, @DanielFischer.  Actually it is more of a rhetorical question.  But thanks for chiming in here.

Comment: @Daniel, note the comment below this question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/301902/347474

Comment: That's good @amWhy.

Comment: Also, this may help many users transition: https://meta.superuser.com/a/12693

Comment: Also see: https://meta.superuser.com/a/12694

Comment: Also, users who have not reached the rep threshold to begin reviewing, see a help icon instead of the review icon, until they reach that rep threshold. Subsequently, the help icon is replaced by the review icon.

Comment: @DanielFischer, Here I'm reflecting back information I've learned, answers I've received after asking question, and some links that I found helpful.  I'm hoping to spare having to address any of this, because, as you've pretty much indicated, you've said, implicitly to all this site's users "Don't ask me"...